# KMP Algorithm Implementation in C++ gives Runtime Error

Tags: c++, algorithm, runtime

I have implemented the Knuth-Morris-Pratt Algorithm in C++ . The implementation seems right however I am encountering a runtime error which I cant seem to figure out . Need Help in that .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int* PrefixFunction(string pattern) {
    int m = pattern.length() ;
    int PrefixTable[m] ;
    PrefixTable[0] = 0 ;
    int k = 0 ;

    for(int q = 1; q<m; q++) {
        while(k>0&&pattern[k]!=pattern[q]) {
            k = PrefixTable[k] ;
        }
        if(pattern[k]==pattern[q]){
            k = k + 1 ;
        }
        PrefixTable[q] = k ;
    }

    return PrefixTable ;
}

void KMP(string text,string pattern) {
    int* PrefixTable = PrefixFunction(pattern) ;
    int n = text.length() ;
    int m = pattern.length() ;
    int q = 0 ; //characters matched

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        while(q>0&&pattern[q]!=text[i]) {
            q = PrefixTable[q] ;
        }
        if(pattern[q]==text[i]) {
            q = q + 1 ;
        }
        if(q==m) {
            cout<<"found : "<<i-m ;
            q = PrefixTable[q] ;
        }
    }

}

int main() {
    string text, pattern ;

    cout<<"Enter the text : " ;
    cin>>text ;

    cout<<"Enter the pattern : " ;
    cin>>pattern ;

    KMP(text,pattern) ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

I get a runtime error after the program asks for input . Guidance needed .

Comment: _"I get a runtime error after the program asks for input"_ Please provide more details regarding the nature of that error.

Comment: Don't mix arrays with pointers. In PrefixFunction, PrefixTable[] is an array whose size should be mentioned using a constexpr. Also after you return from the function, the function stack elements gets popped off and the array elements may not be there where you are trying to access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PrefixFunction` is returning a pointer to a local variable, `PrefixTable`, with automatic storage.
When the function returns, the array ceases to exist, and dereferencing the pointer makes the program undefined.

(What's probably happening specifically in this case is that the calls to `length()` will put their own automatic variables where the array used to be, and when you use those "values" as indexes the program goes boom.)

Consider using `std::vector<int>` instead of an array.

```
std::vector<int> PrefixFunction(string pattern) {
    int m = pattern.length();
    std::vector<int> PrefixTable(m);
    // As before...
```

If you can't use `std::vector`, you could use dynamic allocation (remember to free the memory afterwards), or you could pass the table into the function as a parameter instead of returning it:

```
void PrefixFunction(string pattern, int* PrefixTable)

// ...

void KMP(string text,string pattern) {
    int m = pattern.length();
    int PrefixTable[m];
    PrefixFunction(pattern, PrefixTable);
    // ...
```

Comment: Btw, thanks switching to vector solved it instantly. But for the sake of curiosity do you have a way around with arrays ?

Answer (score 0):

You return a local variable, PrefixTable. But once you've left your function, the stack space of this variable is released. You should either pass it in or allocate it with new.

One nitpicking remark: You're program would be more readable for many if you only start your classes with uppercase, so functions, variables etc. with lowercase.